# Merge specific rows which have the same ID value in a specific column in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, shift

I have a `DataFrame` `df1` with `ID` and `Amount` on specific `Dates`. I try to sum up the `Amount` of two specific rows which have the same `ID` value.

```
df1:
    Date        ID      Amount
0   2022-01-02  1200    10.0
1   2022-01-02  1200    1.0
2   2022-01-02  1400    12.0
3   2022-01-02  1500    11.0
4   2022-01-03  1300    12.5
5   2022-01-03  1300    0.5
6   2022-01-03  1500    12.0
```

This would be the desired output:

```
df1:
    Date        ID      Amount
0   2022-01-02  1200    11 <-- 10+1
1   2022-01-02  1200    0  <-- -1
2   2022-01-02  1400    12
3   2022-01-02  1500    11
4   2022-01-03  1300    13 <-- 12.5+0.5
5   2022-01-03  1300    0  <-- -0.5
6   2022-01-03  1500    12
```

I tried to do it with an `np.where()` to replace the `Amount` where the `shifted` `ID` value is equal to the `ID` value.

For reproducibility:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Date':['2022-01-02', '2022-01-02', '2022-01-02', '2022-01-02', '2022-01-03', '2022-01-03', '2022-01-03'],
    'ID':[1200, 1200, 1400, 1500, 1300, 1300, 1500],
    'Amount':[10, 1, 12, 11, 12.5, 0.5, 12]})
```

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Do you want to do it only for the next immediate row or anywhere in the dataset? In other words is it for all records with matching "ID" or just those next to each other.

Comment: If there is an efficient way for the whole dataset, that would be great. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, it looks like a transaction data and the groups you need are by [Date, ID].

If so, then you can achieve it as:

```py
df1["Amount"] = df1.groupby(["Date", "ID"])["Amount"].transform(lambda x: [x.sum() if i==0 else 0 for i,_ in enumerate(x)])
```

Full example. I have added some additional data the end of the dataset just to test the corner condition with more than 2 entries:

```py
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Date':['2022-01-02', '2022-01-02', '2022-01-02', '2022-01-02', '2022-01-03', '2022-01-03', '2022-01-03', '2022-01-04', '2022-01-04', '2022-01-04'],
    'ID':[1200, 1200, 1400, 1500, 1300, 1300, 1500, 1500, 1500, 1500],
    'Amount':[10, 1, 12, 11, 12.5, 0.5, 12, 10, 3, 5]})

df1["Amount"] = df1.groupby(["Date", "ID"])["Amount"].transform(lambda x: [x.sum() if i==0 else 0 for i,_ in enumerate(x)])

print(df1)

[Out]:
         Date    ID  Amount
0  2022-01-02  1200    11.0
1  2022-01-02  1200     0.0
2  2022-01-02  1400    12.0
3  2022-01-02  1500    11.0
4  2022-01-03  1300    13.0
5  2022-01-03  1300     0.0
6  2022-01-03  1500    12.0
7  2022-01-04  1500    18.0
8  2022-01-04  1500     0.0
9  2022-01-04  1500     0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's try the following code:

```
Amount=[None]*len(df1)

for i in range(1, len(df1)):

    if df1['ID'][i] == df1['ID'][i-1]:

        Amount[i]   = df1['Amount'][i] - df1['Amount'][i]
        Amount[i-1] = df1['Amount'][i] + df1['Amount'][i-1]

    else:

        Amount[i] = df1['Amount'][i]

df1['Amount']=Amount
```

**Output**

```
>>> df1
        Date    ID  Amount
0   2022-01-02  1200    11.0
1   2022-01-02  1200    0.0
2   2022-01-02  1400    12.0
3   2022-01-02  1500    11.0
4   2022-01-03  1300    13.0
5   2022-01-03  1300    0.0
6   2022-01-03  1500    12.0
```